# Can we have two pages with different number of columns?

Tags: two-column

I want to write a paper where the first should consist of a single column and the next page should have 2 column format, is there any command available in Latex, please help

Comment: I was thinking of a more dynamic approach using `\usepackage{everyshi} \AtNextShipout{\twocolumn}`, but any paragraph overflowing from page 1 to 2 is still typeset in `\onecolumn` mode. Subsequent paragraphs, however, is typeset in `\twocolumn` mode.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\twocolumn` for the second page (this command will start a new page):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate filler text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\twocolumn
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Another option would be to use the `multicols` environment from the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package (the environment doesn't start a new page by itself so you might need to use `\newpage`, or `\clearpage` at the end of the first page):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

In this case, you'll have to be careful with the use of floats since only page-wide floats (i.e., `figure*`, `table*`) can be used within the scope of the `multicols` environment.